# How can I get the TimeZone from string?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I have a string which contains the date with time and timezone in it.
I want to convert it to `datetime` with the same timezone given in string.

I have already tried converting string to `datetime` but it converts `datetime` to my system timezone which is different from the one given in the string.

```
Convert.ToDateTime("2019-01-20T08:30:00+02:00")
```

Converts it to my local timezone which is +05:30.

Comment: in which format u want to print your date

Comment: You can extract Time Offset as suggested in @Salah Akbari's answer, but you cannot determine a Time Zone. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159386/is-there-any-delivered-method-which-takes-in-timezoneoffset-of-utc-and-calculate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.8) for this purpose, instead of the `DateTime`:

```
DateTimeOffset dateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-01-20T08:30:00+02:00",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Just don't forget to add the following to your using statements:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: It worth noting that you are talking about Time Offset, and not Time Zone. The difference: most time zones change their offset twice a year (daylight saving). Time zones are represented by TimeZoneInfo class in .NET, and are identified by a string id.